# Homework, stuck on pointers and function call

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Currently it will build and run. but my issue is it won't print out the first print statement in my main function when im trying to call the pointer function. my end goal is to get it to print like a table of values for f() from 1-36. the use of the & and * in those couple lines of code is part of the homework assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


double pointer (double *bi);
double f(double x);
double trapz(int n, double a, double b);
double simpsons(int m, double c, double d);

int main()
{
    int g, h, xii=0;

    double e[35];
    for ( xii=1; xii>36; xii++){
    printf("%d,%f", xii, pointer(&e));
    }


    double x0 = 1, xn = 36, x1 = 1, xm =36;
    int n1 = 35, n2 = 100, n3 = 10000, n4 = 35, n5 = 1000, n6 = 10000;




    printf("For n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n1, trapz(n1, x0, xn));
    printf("For n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n2, trapz(n2, x0, xn));
    printf("For n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n3, trapz(n3, x0, xn));


    printf("for n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n4, simpsons(n4, x1, xm));
    printf("for n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n5, simpsons(n5, x1, xm));
    printf("for n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n6, simpsons(n6, x1, xm));

    printf("Enter the amount of intervals 'n' for the Trapezoidal rule and I'll give you an answer!\n");
    scanf("%d", &g);
    printf("\nYour answer is: %f\n", trapz(g, x0, xn));

    printf("Enter the amount of intervals 'n' for the Simpson's rule and I'll give you an answer!\n");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    printf("\nYour answer is: %f\n", simpsons(h, x1, xm));

    return 0;
}

double pointer (double *bi){

    int xi=0;
    for ( xi=1; xi>36; xi++){
        *bi=f(xi);
    }
return 0;
}

double f(double x)/*function that calculates f(x)*/
{

    double y;

    y = 1000 * sin( 5*x )/(x*x+7.68);

    return y;
}

double trapz(int n, double a, double b)
{
    int i;
    double dx, x, sum;
    dx = (b-a)/n;
    sum=f(a)+f(b);
    for (i=1; i<n; i++){
        x=a+dx*i;
        sum+=2*f(x);
    }
    sum*=dx/2;
    return sum;
}
double simpsons( int m, double c, double d)
{
    int j;
    double dz, z, sum2;
    dz = (d-c)/m;
    sum2 = f(c)+f(d);
    for (j=1; j<m; j++){
        z=c+dz*j;
        sum2 += 2*(j+j%2)*f(z);
    }
    sum2 *= dz/3;
    return sum2;
}
```

update: i edited the pointer function it now is printing but not the right numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


double pointer(double *bi, int ci);
double f(double x);
double trapz(int n, double a, double b);
double simpsons(int m, double c, double d);

int main()
{
    int g, h, xii=0;

    double e[35];
    for ( xii=1; xii<36; xii++){
    printf("\t%d \t\t %f\n", xii, pointer(&e, xii));/*calls function and prints xii,f(xi). 1-36 for xi, and 1-36 for f(xi)*/
    }


    double x0 = 1, xn = 36, x1 = 1, xm =36;
    int n1 = 35, n2 = 100, n3 = 10000, n4 = 35, n5 = 1000, n6 = 10000;




    printf("For n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n1, trapz(n1, x0, xn));
    printf("For n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n2, trapz(n2, x0, xn));
    printf("For n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n3, trapz(n3, x0, xn));


    printf("for n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n4, simpsons(n4, x1, xm));
    printf("for n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n5, simpsons(n5, x1, xm));
    printf("for n = %d, the integral is %f\n", n6, simpsons(n6, x1, xm));

    printf("Enter the amount of intervals 'n' for the Trapezoidal rule and I'll give you an answer!\n");
    scanf("%d", &g);
    printf("\nYour answer is: %f\n", trapz(g, x0, xn));

    printf("Enter the amount of intervals 'n' for the Simpson's rule and I'll give you an answer!\n");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    printf("\nYour answer is: %f\n", simpsons(h, x1, xm));

    return 0;
}

double pointer(double *bi, int ci){
    double ans;
        *bi = (1000 * sin( 5*ci ))/(ci*ci+7.68);
        ans = *bi;
        return ans;

/*function is supposed to return f(xi)*/
}

double f(double x)/*function that calculates f(x)*/
{

    double y;

    y = 1000 * sin( 5*x )/(x*x+7.68);

    return y;
}

double trapz(int n, double a, double b)
{
    int i;
    double dx, x, sum;
    dx = (b-a)/n;
    sum=f(a)+f(b);
    for (i=1; i<n; i++){
        x=a+dx*i;
        sum+=2*f(x);
    }
    sum*=dx/2;
    return sum;
}
double simpsons( int m, double c, double d)
{
    int j;
    double dz, z, sum2;
    dz = (d-c)/m;
    sum2 = f(c)+f(d);
    for (j=1; j<m; j++){
        z=c+dz*j;
        sum2 += 2*(j+j%2)*f(z);
    }
    sum2 *= dz/3;
    return sum2;
}
```

Comment: in your `main` function, the variable `e` is already a `double *`, so you should change `pointer(&e)` to `pointer(e)`. Also, in your `pointer` function, going from `xi  = 1` to `xi > 36` is totally wrong...

Comment: @WhatsUp Is close, but `e` is an *array*. It can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. I.e. using plain `e` is the same as `&e[0]`. The type of that iwll be `double *`. The expression `&e` is something else completely, it's a pointer to the *array*, which will have the type `double (*)[35]`. That's probably not the source of your problem though, as both `&e[0]` and `&e` will (fortunately for you!) point to the same location.

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, you should [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `for ( xii=1; xii>36; xii++)` the condition fails on the first check.

Comment: A couple of hints about your problem though (all in the `pointer` function): Think about that loop condition. If `xi` is initialized to `1`, will the loop condition `xi > 36` be true? Furthermore, Do you ever make `bi` point somewhere else inside the loop? If not, then what is the meaning of the expression `*bi = f(xi)`?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the the compiler warnings:

```
16:34: warning: passing argument 1 of 'pointer' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     printf("%d,%f", xii, pointer(&e));
                                  ^
5:8: note: expected 'double *' but argument is of type 'double (*)[35]'
 double pointer (double *bi);
```

The `e` is pointer to the expected double array inside pointer function:

```
double e[35];

printf("%d,%f", xii, pointer(e));
```

Also your intentions my be to iterate over all elements of e:

```
for ( xii=0; xii<35; xii++){
printf("%d,%f", xii, pointer(e));
}
```

After a such calculations:

```
double pointer (double *bi){

    int xi=0;
    for ( xi=0; xi<35; xi++){
        bi[xi] = f(xi);
    }
    return 0;
}
```